# Ceylon Run Configuration: can't find project

Tags: eclipse, ceylon

I am trying to create a run configuration for a Ceylon project that I cloned from my remote repository. First step in making a run configuration is to identify the relevant project. I chose 'Open projects from File system' and opened the cloned folder ('milling'). The project folders showed up as expected.

However, when trying to choose the project from the Run Configuration dialogue, the selector windows is absolutely blank. I can't browse to point to the chosen project:

[image]

I have already followed [this guide](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/ide/eclipse/), seemingly successful. I thus think Ceylon is installed and ready to run, if I could just point to my project folder.

Worth noting:

- My Workspace folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt`
- My project folder is `C:\Users\Jon\Aukitekt\milling`
- Eclipse Oxygen version: `Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200`

Comment: I suspect that the project might not be configured as a Ceylon project (for instance, the icon for the `.ceylon` files doesn’t look familiar), but unfortunately I don’t have a working Eclipse+Ceylon setup to compare with right now.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I created a new project (Ceylon), then pasted the content of my code folder (from another computer) on top of the new project folder. That solved this problem.

Comment: @loldrup could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Lucas Werkeister suggested that the project might not have been created as a Ceylon project.
Therefore I created a new project (Ceylon), then pasted the content of my code folder (from another computer) on top of the new project folder. That solved this problem.

Comment: Additionally, if you’re brave enough, you could try editing .project file directly, adding Ceylon nature to it manually.